Can I make upper mepc bits read-only zero? How to decide?

mepc is a WARL register that must be able to hold all valid virtual addresses. It need not be capable of holding all possible invalid addresses. Prior to writing mepc, implementations may convert an invalid address into some other invalid address that mepc is capable of holding.

This is written in RISC-V Privileged Architectures V20211203 I wanted to know the correct behaviour here. I thought I could make the upper bits than valid virtual address length (let us say VLEN) as read-only zero to get more optimized hardware (no need for additional registers and ports and also additional access fault source in my design). However, I don't know the effect in reality. I mean with this optimization, would I mislead the software? For example, privileged software may write mepc that my design keeps only VLEN bits and mret jump to irrelevant regions and doesn't trap as access fault.
It is mentioned that an invalid address can be converted to another invalid address that mepc is capable of holding, in quotation. So I can make the design mepc slightly bigger than VLEN. However, I also wonder if this would also mislead the same software because the mepc will not be the same as it was written previously. The software can control each time whether it writes mepc correctly or not as it is done in checking valid pmpaddr configuration. However, this might be a performance loss.
How to decide the design here? Did I strain for small improvements here?
